# setTimeout in form.submit() method does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying `setTimeout()` function in form submit. However before executing the function the form gets submitted and anything inside the timeout function is not getting executed. Below is the code snippet.

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $("#myform").submit(function() {
          setTimeout(function(){
               alert("me after 1000 mili seconds");
               return false;              
          }, 1000);

    });
};
```

Kindly help me on how to resolve this issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function () {
     var submit = false;
     $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("me after 1000 mili seconds");
              submit = true;
              $("#myform").submit(); // if you want            
          }, 1000);
          if(!submit)
              e.preventDefault();
     });
};
```

Comment: It really worked for me... thank you so much. you saved my day.

I just moved if(!submit){...} before setTimeout. Thank you sooo much.

Answer (score 2):

The form is submitting straight away. You need to delegate the default action. This should work for you:

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("me after 1000 mili seconds");
          }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Please see this [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cuGSu/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the submit action on the form, you could try:

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          setTimeout(function(){
          alert("me after 1000 mili seconds");
          return false;

        }, 1000);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you forgotten closing brace `)` in last line

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          setTimeout(function(){
          alert("me after 1000 mili seconds");
          return false;

        }, 1000);

    });
});
 ^---- here you forgotten to put brace.
```