# jQuery submit refreshes the page instead of submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have written the following script to submit the form with a delay:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form-submit').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //  event.stopPropagation();
        $('#big-dots-loader').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
        $('#wait-please').show();
        $('#cities-holder').empty();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#new-item-form").submit();
        }, 3000);
        //$('#form-submit').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Now when I click on the button, the delay occurs but the form does not get submitted to the specified URL and rather the page refreshes.

What could be the reason?

Here is also the form opening tag:

```
<form id="new-item-form" 
    action="<?php echo base_url("process/ads/new"); ?>"
    method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Comment: Is the value for `action` attribute correct?

Comment: Usually, when a page is refreshed when firing submit of a FORM, that means FORM is submited. I don't understand your issue. Check your network tab, is the action URL of FORM accurate?

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:php]?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407091/settimeout-in-form-submit-method-does-not-work

Comment: yes the URL is accurate and in case of inaccuracy it should come up with 404. I have check it without the script, it gets submitted correctly.

Comment: Now please provide submit button HTML markup

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent form submit from redirecting/refreshing using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213975/prevent-form-submit-from-redirecting-refreshing-using-javascript)

Comment: I'm still wondering what makes OP think FORM is not submitted, beacuse page refresh so, FORM should be submitted AFAIK

Comment: @Mostafa: the action might be pointing to the same page, it could be empty, may be there is more than `#new-item-form`, or the target page redirects you to the same page. Any of these correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$(window).load(function () {
     var submit = false;


     $('#form-submit').on('click', function (event) {
     $('#big-dots-loader').css(
        'display': 'block'
    );
    $('#wait-please').show();
    $('#cities-holder').empty();
          setTimeout(function(){
              $("#new-item-form").submit();   
          }, 3000);
          if(!submit)
              event.preventDefault();
     });
};
```

Comment: Why `var submit = false;`? Does the `variable` make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not sure what gets called or what is submitted, look on the request data.

On Firefox browser you can use Firebug plugin and look at the Network tab to see if the form gets submitted or not and which params are POSTed.

Similarly, on Chrome browser, you can use built-in Dev Tools (F12) to look at network requests (you should check 'Preserve log upon navigation' so that the network log is not lost).

Also check in the browser console window that the js does't report any error. The error in the js stops the js execution and often leads to tricky behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code, this will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form-submit').submit(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();    
         $('#big-dots-loader').css({'display':'block'});
         $('#wait-please').show();
         $('#cities-holder').empty();
         setTimeout(function(){$("#new-item-form").submit();}, 3000);                    

         return false;
     });         
});
```

`#form-submit` should be the id of `<form>` tag

Comment: You are already preventing default behaviour, so why returning false? And if `#form-submit` is ID of FORM, what is `#new-item-form`???

Comment: Yes you are right, but we can go with return false, which we are usually doing for the form which we do want to submit after some business logic.
But you are right !!!! It really make sense either keep event.preventDefault() or return false

Comment: Ya true, because return false in jQuery is just shortcut for prevent default behaviour and stop bubbling of event

Comment: Wolf, but I think if we either remove preventDefault or return false, remaining implementation is correct ... Please suggest.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Be aware, i'm not the downvoter ;)